# When is tuple length too long?

Tags: mysql, tuples, schema

Here is a logical schema for my largest relation:

`{(id, uName, supplies, score, playerType, storageSupplies, supplyDrop, barracks, armourDepot, hangar, droneHangar, storage, offensive, defensive, infantry, vehicles, air, fuel, explored, morale, cash, population, tax, food, aSector, cSector, iSector, XP)}`

As you can see, each tuple is going to be very long. This is starting to become very cumbersome as attributes are added. The thing is, there is only ever a 1-to-1 relationship so while it would help organisation and avoid obfuscation by breaking this relation up into smaller, meta related relations, wouldn't it add more overhead? Or should I not worry about mysql efficiency when this relation will have tens of thousands of tuples at the most, realistically.

Comment: 10k rows barely can be an issue even with most terrible queries and without indexes at all.

Comment: So would you personally have all of these user attributes in one long table or organise them into a few?

Comment: I'd would definitely start with the most obvious solution, yes. No one could predict a bottleneck, and even huge and loaded project like twitter and facebook improve their schema *iteratively*, after a lot of measurements and profilings. Even such smart engineers like they have cannot predict future issues - so they solve them as long as issues appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Assuming your table is max 10k rows, rarely updated and rarely read (compared to other entities in the database) - you are right efficiency will see no great benefit, however...

2) Every little bit counts; for example with table this small most of it can be kept in memory and you will have very fast SELECTS; if a lot of attributes are mostly NULLS then splitting the table would reduce the SIZE of it and would free RAM for other caches; reduce necessary I/O when updating (generally make the things more scalable). The expense is the slight increase of complexity (for updates, SELECTS can use a VIEW).

3) 'Overhead' for splitting 1-to-1 relations is misconception; it largely depends on the workload - you can construct cases that prefer things broken down into two smaller tables and you can construct cases that benefit from having the data stored in one table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure what constitutes as rarely read/written but the database is the storage for an online game programmed in PHP and most scripts always interact with this table, so I'd say it can be heavily used when thousands of players are playing. Excellent answer with some great things to consider.Thanks.

Comment: The rarely read and written is a relative comparison to another table - let's say players move units and every move is written into the DB. That would be a table that is often written to. Or table with a log of all actions of all players. Compared to that (and depending on the type of the game) users and their stats might not need so much reading and writing.

Answer (score 1):

> The internal representation of a table has a maximum row size of
>   65,535 bytes

Eficiency depends on the MySQL version and the Storage Engine you are using. But you should know that doing this will increase data to be cached that might not be necesary.

For example, a `Users` table might increase if we add address data of users, and that data maybe is not needed frequently, so, spliting it into 2 tables: `Users` and `Users_address` will be more efficient becouse if the table Users is heavily read it could be cached.

There are other considerations like maintenance and index work.